# Windows Vista ADB driver for Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, windows-vista, adb

For app development purposes, I would like to access Samsung Galaxy S3 phone through ADB interface on my Windows vista 32 bit laptop. Where can I find the ADB driver for the phone?

carrier: wind (canada)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the phone on [Samsung's website](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/main/supportMain.do), go to downloads, and install the driver from there.

Comment: I found my own solution, I needed to download this:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows